# How to check session before executing jquery preloader function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session, dom

I am trying to check session when my page loads , but when my page is loading it is calling preloader function first.
     I want to check session before executing jquery preloader function.

**Code for my preloader function:**

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {
$('#work-in-progress').fadeOut(100);
});
```

I wants my preloader function to execute only if my session is false.
     for example in my below code if spl is false then only I want to execute preloader function else I dont want to execute it.

**Code for checking session:**

```
var spl=('<?php echo $_SESSION['splash'] ?>');
if(!spl==true)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your script tag, if PHP var `$_SESSION['splash']` is FALSE, then write the jQuery `.bind` function:

```
<?php if ( !$_SESSION['splash'] ) { ?>

$(window).bind("load", function () {
    $('#work-in-progress').fadeOut(100);
});

<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like:

```
<? if ($_SESSION['splash']): ?>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            // do work
        })
    </script>
<? endif; ?>
```

???

---

also, `if(!spl==true)` is very confusing. You're expecting `spl` to be a `Boolean`, correct? Well, if `spl = false`, then your `if statement` will read `if false is not false equal to true` which is to say `if (true == true)`